# Android TextView Allocation

Tags: android, textview

I have 5 - 6 `TextView` in activity 1 as follows:

```
textChallenge = new TextView(context.getApplicationContext());
    textChallenge.setTypeface(fontJoan);
    textChallenge.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textChallenge.setText("99");
    textChallenge.measure((int)Define.getScreenWidth(), (int)Define.getScreenHeight());
    textChallenge.layout(0, 0, 200, 200);
    textChallenge.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 20);
    textChallenge.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    textChallenge.buildDrawingCache();
```

I have textChallenger, textUser, textBestScore etc. When I start activity 2 and come back to

activity 1. I check my allocation by using `(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1048576L)`.

I found that allocation sizes are increased a little bit every time I come back to activity 1.

How can I suppose to free these `TextView` allocation? I try to `setText("")` but I got

`NullPointerException`. I have to create by programmatically, so I can't using `findViewByID`.

And I try `textChallenge.getDrawingCache().recycle(); textChallenge = null;`.

However, my heap allocation sizes are still increased. Please give me some advices, Thanks.

Comment: try to give context instead of context.getApplicationContext()

Comment: I did it. Nothing changes :(

Comment: initially declare the textChallenge = null where it is declare in activty 1. did u use it destroyDrawingCache ?

Comment: Do you mean `textChallenge = null;` `textChallenge = new TextView(context);` ?

Comment: why you want to release these textviews ?

Comment: Because I check allocation size by `(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1048576L)` and it incrases a little bit every time I come back to activity 1. I think this mean mem leak.

Comment: I think that you should use a real profiling tool to find out if you really have a memory leak, or whether the garbage collector just hasn't run when you expect it to. Are you ever actually running out of memory?

Comment: Yes, I did. Now I just comment code and print value to find mem leak. I create only `TextView` and check my alloc size. And I found that it increases.